# Inserting values with python wrapper for KSQLDB

Tags: python, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

im trying to enrich a stream with more data. F.E: I have a stream and need to add a calculated field based on the data. After getting the new data for the new Column i want to insert the row with the enriched field into a new Stream. When im doing it with the KSQLCLI, it works. When i use the python Wrapper Client it ain't inserting the values.
Any help is appreciated
Code:

```
client.ksql("""CREATE STREAM STREAM_COMPASS_UPDATE (ROWKEY BIGINT KEY, ID BIGINT, SCREENNAME STRING, TEXT STRING, LOCATION STRING, LANG STRING, LAT DOUBLE, LONG DOUBLE, PLACE_NAME STRING, PLACE_STREET STRING, PLACE_FULLNAME STRING, RETWEET BOOLEAN, COMPASS_DIRECTION STRING) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='TWEETS_GER_USERLOCATION_PLACE_COMPASS', PARTITIONS`=2, REPLICAS=1, VALUE_FORMAT='Avro');""")
```

Insert the data with new column(compass_direction):

```
q= """INSERT INTO STREAM_COMPASS_UPDATE (text, location, ID, SCREENNAME, LANG, LAT, LONG, PLACE_NAME, PLACE_STREET, PLACE_FULLNAME, RETWEET, COMPASS_DIRECTION) VALUES ("""+ "'" + text + "','"+ i.location.replace(',',';').encode('utf-8', 'replace').decode() + "',"+ str(last_id) + ",'" + str(i.user) + "','" + str(i.lang) + "'," + str(i.lat) + "," + str(i.long) + "," + str(i.place_name) + ","+  str(i.place_street) +","+ str(i.place_fullname) + "," + str(i.retweet) + "," + "'" + str(i.compass_direction) + "');""" 

client.query(q)
```

When i print out the query and copy paste it into the KSQLDB CLI the row gets inserted. When i do it with the python wrapper no data gets inserted into the stream.
What am i missing or doing wrong?

pythonwrapper: https://github.com/bryanyang0528/ksql-python

Answer (score -1):

Try client.ksql(q) instead of client.query(q)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ... client.ksql is not for inserting data...